# Implementation of Time Machine Feature in grails application

Tags: grails, history

I am trying to implement a 'time machine' feature in my grails application. The feature would allow user to select a date in past and would display the interface of the application that was on the selected date. How do I implement this feature? I was thinking of adding a 'dateCreated' field for all domains, so that in the time machine feature, I could query all the results with created date before the selected date. I think this would work but as the data would grow, the size of database would grow and at that time the application would be heavy. Is there any other way to do this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe draw some inspiration from this related question:

[How to manage object revisions in Grails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564936/how-to-manage-object-revisions-in-grails)

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the http://grails.org/plugin/audit-logging plugin since it will allow you to keep all versions of domain class instances. But implementing this feature will be pretty tricky since object don't exist in isolation - you'll need to not only display the data as of the previous date, but its related data (e.g. the author's books collection) as of that date too. It will make the queries quite complicated.